# npm ERR! appium-chromedriver@3.1.4 install: `node install-npm.js`

Tags: node.js, npm, appium

Install appium on os x

Command execute:$ sudo npm install -g appium@1.7.2

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/2018422-31132-799ew3.4ynnk'
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! appium-chromedriver@3.1.4 install: `node install-npm.js`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the appium-chromedriver@3.1.4 install script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
>   /Users/oliveira/.npm/_logs/2018-05-23T01_24_48_805Z-debug.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change ownership of your node_modules folder with

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/node_modules/`

Answer (score 0):

Either change the ownership of the whole node project by

```
sudo chown -R userName pathToProject
```

-R will recursively change the ownership of all the directory and files inside the project.

If you don't want to change the ownership you can run the command by the superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `sudo` when you are installing Appium via `npm`.

There is from Appium website:

> "Make sure you have not installed Node or Appium with sudo, otherwise
>   you'll run into problems). We recommend the latest stable version,
>   though Appium supports Node 6+."